# Tensorflow and keras get same output prediction error

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, image-processing, keras

So i learned to create image recognition for rock, paper, scissor. so the type of model will be categorical. 
the program getting error when i trying to predict the output is always the same. so here the output and code:

```
import numpy as np
from google.colab import files
from keras.preprocessing import image
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.image as mpimg
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.image as mpimg
%matplotlib inline

uploaded = files.upload()

for fn in uploaded.keys():

  # predicting images
  path = fn
  img = image.load_img(path, target_size=(150,150))
  imgplot = plt.imshow(img)
  x = image.img_to_array(img)
  x = np.expand_dims(x, axis=0)

  images = np.vstack([x])
  classes = model.predict(images, batch_size=30)
  model.summary()
  print(classes[0:10])
```

Output :

```
Saving p4.jpg to p4 (4).jpg
Model: "sequential_4"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
conv2d_12 (Conv2D)           (None, 148, 148, 32)      896       
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_12 (MaxPooling (None, 74, 74, 32)        0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_13 (Conv2D)           (None, 72, 72, 64)        18496     
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_13 (MaxPooling (None, 36, 36, 64)        0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_14 (Conv2D)           (None, 34, 34, 128)       73856     
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_14 (MaxPooling (None, 17, 17, 128)       0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_15 (Conv2D)           (None, 15, 15, 128)       147584    
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_15 (MaxPooling (None, 7, 7, 128)         0         
_________________________________________________________________
flatten_3 (Flatten)          (None, 6272)              0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_8 (Dense)              (None, 256)               1605888   
_________________________________________________________________
dropout (Dropout)            (None, 256)               0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_9 (Dense)              (None, 3)                 771       
=================================================================
Total params: 1,847,491
Trainable params: 1,847,491
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
[[1. 0. 0.]]
```

I don't know really well about machine learning. so i hope got some problem fixed for this program. for the addition i added some full code from my program. here is:

```
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
                    rescale=1./255,
                    rotation_range=20,
                    horizontal_flip=True,
                    shear_range = 0.2,
                    fill_mode = 'nearest')

test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
                    rescale=1./255,
                    rotation_range=20,
                    horizontal_flip=True,
                    shear_range = 0.2,
                    fill_mode = 'nearest')

train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
        train_dir,  
        target_size=(150, 150),  
        batch_size=32,
        class_mode='categorical')

validation_generator = test_datagen.flow_from_directory(
        validation_dir, 
        target_size=(150, 150), 
        batch_size=32, 
        class_mode='categorical')


model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32, (3,3), activation='relu', input_shape=(150, 150, 3)),
    tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(2, 2),
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(64, (3,3), activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(2,2),
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(128, (3,3), activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(2,2),
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(128, (3,3), activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(2,2),
    tf.keras.layers.Flatten(),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(256, activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.5),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(3, activation = 'softmax')
])


model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              optimizer=tf.optimizers.Adam(),
              metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(
      train_generator,
      # steps_per_epoch=25,
      epochs=20,
      batch_size=32,
      validation_data=validation_generator, 
      # validation_steps=5,
      verbose=2)
```

for output fit:
[output.fit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7mzBV.png)

Comment: What's the error are you getting?

Comment: what is the problem you're having?

Comment: the problem is the prediction always getting output like this in every image[[1. 0. 0.]]

Answer (score 0):

You aren't doing rescale for your input images. Try to divide input images by 255 before running predict()

```
classes = model.predict(images/255.0, batch_size=30)
```

Comment: the code of :
img = image.load_img(path, target_size=(150,150))
is this rescale the input image or not ?
and if not what is the code

Comment: No, the train_datagen has parameter rescale=1./255 which means it divides each image by 255 before training. But predict function gets images without this modification

Comment: okee after i trying to add your code now the output prediction different again, this the output:
[[9.9998391e-01 1.6114020e-05 7.1954855e-09]]

sorry, im new in ml sir